# Getting error while biding in relaychain for adding my parachain into relay-chain

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, auctions

I'm trying to connect my `parachain` to a `relay-chain` locally via `auction.`
I bid in the `auction` and set the auction ending period to `2 minutes,`

[image]

```
 The bidding process is done but after the bidding I got this error.
```

[image]

Comment: Please include exact steps on how to reproduce this issue

Comment: I got the solution.thnaks for your effort @Bruno

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting might be due to the `api-version` of `polkajs explorer`,

> The bidding process is done but after the bidding I got this error.

After bidding you were not able to get any slot because of the timings I can see in the screenshot that `ending period` is also `2 mins`, my guess is when you changed the timing of `epoch`, you didn't changed the time for `lease period`, so after the bidding ends your `launch period` starts but the `lease period` is still not active.

`Lease period` should start before the bid ends so that you can launch your parachain.